# Как подключить файл стилей к определенной странице на WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Например, у меня есть главная страница, на которой должен быть подключен только main.css, а на странице товара product-page.css, на странице контактов contact.css и т.д.

У меня пока что main.css подключен в function.php через enqueue-script-style

```
function rebus_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'rebus-font-awesome', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), 'null', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'rebus-css-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css', array() , null, 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'rebus-js-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.min.js', array(), null, true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rebus_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
if( is_page( $page ) ){
     //подключаем стили 
}
```

`$page` - идентификатор страницы

про функцию `is_page` читаем доку https://wp-kama.ru/function/is_page

Comment: А как мне узнать ID той или иной страницы?

Comment: зайдите в админку найдите страницу, перейдите в редактирование и там в адресной строке будет `id`